# Django/Jquery.formset: how to leave space beetween form of fomrset when using 'add new' button?

Tags: jquery, django, inline-formset

I have a 'cosmetic' problem using Jquery.formset.

I have a form with nested subform (formset) and I use JQuery to add (or remove) subform (remove and add new buttons)

The 'problem' is that subform are added but collapse

I would like new subform added with 
 but don't know how to proceed...

thanks for your help

html

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Utilisateurs | Mereva{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<!-- Source code: https://codewithmark.com/easily-edit-html-table-rows-or-cells-with-jquery -->
<!-- Source code: https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html -->
<div class='container'>
    <br>        
    <br>
    <h1 id="utilisateur" data-parameters="">Formulaire utilisateur</h1>
    <br><br>

    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <form id="utilisateureditform" method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <br><br><div class="dropdown-divider"></div><br><br>
        <h2>Applications</h2><br><br>
        <!-- {{ application|crispy }} -->

        {{ application.management_form }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">Nom de l'application</p></div>
            <div class="col-5"><p>Droits</p></div>
            <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>      
        {% for application_form in application %}

        <div class="row link-formset">
            {% if application_form.instance.pk %}{{ application_form.DELETE }}{% endif %}
            <div class="col-6">

                    {{ application_form.app_app_nom }}
                    {% if application_form.app_app_nom.errors %}
                        {% for error in application_form.app_app_nom.errors %}
                            {{ error|escape }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

            </div>
            <div class="col-5">

                    {{ application_form.app_dro }}
                    {% if application_form.app_dro.errors %}
                        {% for error in application_form.app_dro.errors %}
                            {{ error|escape }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

            </div>
            <div class="hidden">{{ application_form.app_ide }}</div>
        </div><br>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if application.non_form_errors %}
            {% for error in application.non_form_errors %}
                {{ error|escape }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %} 

        <br>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Valider" style="width: 100px;">
        <a data-modal data-target="" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'project:index' %}" style="width: 100px;">Annuler</a>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
{% block extrabody %}
<script src="{% static 'project/js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.link-formset').formset({
        addText: 'Ajouter',
        deleteText: 'Supprimer',
        prefix: '{{ application.prefix }}'
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('html body div.container form#utilisateureditform.post-form a.add-row').before('<br>');
    });


</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS for syling and managing the presentation layer of your application.

A new CSS class can help create the space you need.

Add the class to your `<div>`.

```html
{{ application.management_form }}
<div class="row make-space-below">
```

Then add a `<style>` tag to your template.

```html
<style>
    .make-space-below {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

This a little hacky. In general you should try and have a `.css` file that holds your styles. The `.css` file can be cached in the browser reducing request to your server and the size of your `.html` files.

Comment: I have already try but it dosen't works, probably because row are not yet in the DOM but added when user click add new

Comment: Styles are evaluated every time the browser paints an element. So, it does not matter when it changes. Open dev tools and see what styles are applied to the element. If you need you can add `!important` to override a styles that has higher precedence in the cascade.

Comment: You are right, thanks ; I used JQuery .css(margin-bottom: 50px;) that doesn't works...